How to get the value in a rich text field in Dynamics 365
I am trying to return the string value from a rich text field in Dynamics 365 using a javascript function. This does not work the normal way since the field is formatted to rich text and instead returns a very long text.
How do I extract just the string value from the user input?
I tried the normal
var str = formContext.getAttribute("description"); which returns a long text to my string variable. Since it is rich text it cannot be sliced and diced and instead needs to be converted somehow I guess

If you want just the text from an HTML content (the one saved inside a Rich Text field) you can use the following script:
function parseHTML(html) {
    let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    return doc.body.textContent || "";
}

function test_richtext_OnChange(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    let richTextValue = formContext.getAttribute("test_richtext").getValue();
    let cleanValue = parseHTML(richTextValue);
    formContext.getAttribute("test_plaintext").setValue(cleanValue);
}

I also wrote a small post about this with a screenshot: Rich Text to Plain Text conversion inside Power Apps
